# Generalized polynomial chaos with periodic basis function?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, stochastic-processes, periodic-functions, stochastic-approximation

In generalized polynomial chaos expansion, polynomial orthogonal to the distribution of uncertain (random) parameter is used. For example, for normally distributed random variable Hermite polynomial is used and for uniformly distributed parameter Legendre polynomial is used because they are perfectly orthogonal to their respective distribution. My question is: Is it possible to use any periodic function as an orthogonal function? Is there is any periodic function exist that is orthogonal to normally distributed random variable?

Comment: I thought the Hermite polynomials $H_n$ are orthogonal with respect to the normal weighted pdf. That is $\int H_n(x)H_m(x) e^{-x^2/2} dx = \sqrt{2\pi} n! \delta_{nm}$ and the legendre polynomials $P_n$ are orthogonal against the uniform weighted pdf $\int_a^b P_n(x)P_m(x)\alpha dx \sim \delta_{mn}$

Comment: Thanks, @N8tron, did I make any mistake?  I think I wrote the same thing. Can you point out where did I go wrong, please?